# SELECT PPSE GIVES 6700,( VISA Paywave)

Tags: javacard, apdu, contactless-smartcard, emv

I have two different smartcard chips with Visa Paywave inside (one is native, and other is Java Card).

I am trying to run select PPSE or select Application command, one card is giving the expected result while another card is giving status word `6700`.

```
Command ---->CMD 00A404000E325041592E5359532E4444463031
Sw1-sw2 <----67 00
Command ---->CMD 00A4040007A0000000031010
Sw1-sw2 <----67 00
```

We have some other proprietary test tool that is receiving a good result for both cards. That means that both cards have a PPSE and application in it. I wonder why my tool is sending the same command but getting a different result.

Any advice would be helpful here.

Comment: Try Sending `00A40400` and the add the result to your question please :)

Comment: @Abraham    Command ---->CMD 00A40400
    Sw1-sw2 <----67 00 , getting 6700.

Comment: Can you try the `SELECT` command with a _Le_ field? I.e. something like `00A404000E325041592E5359532E444446303100` and/or `00A4040007A000000003101000`?

Comment: @vlp ,  I found the same, here i need to set Le=0 , card is looking for Le thats why giving 6700 when not getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know that there are 4 cases defined in ISO7816-4 like,

[image: APDU CASES:-]

As per my experience maximum card does not worry about Le field in apdu command, card O.S just process the command and return data if require.

Here i am getting error -6700 because here my card is expecting Le byte too.( card expecting case 4 instead of case 3)
Send command like below solve my problem,

```
00 A4 04 00 0E 325041592E5359532E4444463031 00 ( adding Le = 0x00 at last)
```

Comment: It is a good practice to follow the command documentation/specification regarding ISO cases -- sometimes it _could_ cause you severe trouble (like now or with `T=0` cards in general). Side note: You will not be able to accept your own answer for ~24hours.